# Overlay dropdown content CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a section bar that displays a dropdown with some data when the mouse hovers over it. It works fine. But after implementing slider code this dropdown scrolls.

Section contains displays in 30 height. But I want to display those dropdown over on other div.

When I remove `overflow-x: hidden` it works fine but that time screen not look good.

I tried using `z-index`, overflow but without success.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="parent">
        <div class="contentBlock">1</div>
        <div class="contentBlock">2</div>
        <div class="contentBlock">3</div>
        <div class="contentBlock">4</div>
        <div class="contentBlock">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<span id="panLeft" class="panner" data-scroll-modifier='-1'>Left</span>

<span id="panRight" class="panner" data-scroll-modifier='1'>Right</span>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width:600px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#parent {
    width:6000px;
}
.contentBlock {
    font-size:10em;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:400px;
    height:400px;
    width:500px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.panner {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:45%;
}
.active {
    color:red;
}
#panLeft {
    left:0px;
}
#panRight {
    right:0px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function () {

    var scrollHandle = 0,
        scrollStep = 5,
        parent = $("#container");

    //Start the scrolling process
    $(".panner").on("mouseenter", function () {
        var data = $(this).data('scrollModifier'),
            direction = parseInt(data, 10);

        $(this).addClass('active');

        startScrolling(direction, scrollStep);
    });

    //Kill the scrolling
    $(".panner").on("mouseleave", function () {
        stopScrolling();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    //Actual handling of the scrolling
    function startScrolling(modifier, step) {
        if (scrollHandle === 0) {
            scrollHandle = setInterval(function () {
                var newOffset = parent.scrollLeft() + (scrollStep * modifier);

                parent.scrollLeft(newOffset);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling() {
        clearInterval(scrollHandle);
        scrollHandle = 0;
    }

}());
```

Comment: I am used http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/atAHh/ scroll.

Comment: maybe You should use position:absolute;

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: @ Thank you but it's not working for me.

Comment: where's the header code?